# Mouse hotspot off by a few pixels, on only one screen

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics-card

Occasionally, I have an issue where the mouse hotspot will be about 10-20px off. For example, mouseovers and clicks will be detected to one side of where the cursor appears to be pointing.

I have a multi-monitor system consisting of an eyefinity-6 array and three additional monitors. This only occurs on one screen. Not a specific one, but one at a time. It comes and goes. I've gone through several video cards, all ATI, and this has happened on and off throughout the years.

A cold boot corrects the problem.

What could cause this?

Comment: I would be interested to know if it happens on an NVIDIA card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unfortunate solution is to reboot or restart the display adapter.